# add a pause in running each line of a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

```
function change ()
{
    for( var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) ;
    {     
        alert(5) ;
    }
}
```

alert 5.after i click OK,waiting for 5s,alert 5 again,waiting for 5.and do this for 5 times.
but it doesn't work correctly with the setTimeout function

UPDATE: Here is what I'm really trying to do:

```
var groopBox = $("#"+value.value+" .group") ;
for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ ) {
     groopBox.eq(i).slideToggle(1000)
}
```

This works but when i put this code block in `setTimeout` it doesn't work:

```
var groopBox = $("#"+value.value+" .group") ;
for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ ) {
     setTimeout(function(){ groopBox.eq(i).slideToggle(1000) }, i*2000)
}
```

Comment: What `setTimeout` function?

Comment: it doesnt work correctly.when i use setTime out it runs the for loop after 5s and run all of the alerts consecutively.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if something "doesn't work correctly" it's probably your code. So we need to see what didn't work...

Comment: i want to alert-wai-alert-wait... but with using setTimeout,it willbe like this wait-alert-alert-alert...

Comment: JS doesn't have a `sleep` function

Comment: Both Blair and my answer will work. You simply have to do some level of recursion where the setTimeout is run AFTER the alert, otherwise they will all execute asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is the way. See http://jsfiddle.net/scythah/aA6nV/1/ for a working example.

```
(function () {
    var i = 0;
    change();

    function change() {
        if (i < 5) {
            i++;
            alert(5);
            setTimeout(change, 5000);
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: global variables are _evil_

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - No they're not. At least, there _are_ appropriate uses for them. But who says `i` is even global? Maybe all of the above code would be included inside another function? (It _is_ included inside another function in the fiddle demo...)

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be global. Here, I'll update the answer with an example of a way that it *isn't* global.

Comment: Why not make `change` an IIFE too, and eliminate the explicit call to it?

Comment: Yes @Alnitak you can do that too. I always try to limit the changes made from the original question though so that the OP can hopefully see how their code has been changed. If you completely re-write everything it can be difficult to see what changes.

Comment: why all functions run and at last the setTimeOut run?i want alert something after setTime out run.but when i put alert after setTimeOut line,it first run alert then run setTimeout what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE now that OP has provided the "real" code:**

The problem with putting this:

```
groopBox.eq(i).slideToggle(1000)
```

in a call to `setTimeout()` that is in a loop is that by the time all of the timeouts run the `for` loop has finished and `i` will be equal to `5`, and since there is no element with index `5` for `.eq(5)` nothing happens. You can get around that by introducing an extra "wrapper" function so that the required index ends up in a closure:

```
var groopBox = $("#"+value.value+" .group");
for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ ) {
   (function(j) {
      setTimeout(function() { groopBox.eq(j).slideToggle(1000) }, i * 2000);
   })(i);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCgkC/

The loop's `i` is passed into the anonymous function as `j` and then the code *inside* the timeout uses `j`.

Or you can do it rather more simply by using jQuery's [`.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), noting that `.delay()` is *not* a general replacement for `setTimeout()`, it is used only for delaying things in an element's jQuery animation queue:

```
var groopBox = $("#"+value.value+" .group");
for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ ) {
   groopBox.eq(i).delay(i * 2000).slideToggle(1000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCgkC/1/

**My original answer:**

Note that your code had an incorrect semicolon at the end of this line:

```
for( var i=0 ; i<5 ; i++) ;
```

...which means the block enclosed in `{}` isn't part of the `for` loop.

`setTimeout()` is the function used to delay execution of JavaScript code by a specified interval:

```
function change () {
    for( var i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++)
    {     
        setTimeout(function() { alert(5) }, i * 5000);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kNvXh/

JavaScript doesn't have a "blocking" pause or sleep function that prevents the next line of code from running until after the pause. The [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) schedules a function to run after the specified number of milliseconds, but then execution continues immediately with the statement after `setTimeout()`. So the function I've shown above runs the entire loop, queues up five timeouts five seconds apart - note how the delay specified is multiplied by the loop counter, and then ends - after each delay the queued functions are called.

This lack of a "blocking" facility means you can't have whatever code called `change()` wait for all of the alerts before continuing. If you need to wait you need to restructure your code (perhaps with callback functions) to allow for the non-blocking nature of JS timeouts.

Comment: now i use this code : var groopBox = $("#"+value.value+" .group") ;
 for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ )
 {
  groopBox.eq(i).slideToggle(1000)
        } it works but when i put this code block in setTime out it doesnt work(i copy/paste this code into this setTimeout(function(){...},i*2000)but it doesnt work

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should have put that code in the question in the first place, because that's a different (closure, or lack thereof) issue. I've edited your question to copy that code into it to make it clearer to everybody what you're trying to do. I had to apply some interpretation to your comment about exactly where you put the `setTimeout()`, so please review my edit and fix it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
function myAlert(callback){
  return function(){
    alert(5);
    if(callback){
      setTimeout(callback, 5000);
    }
  }
}

var i = 5, exec;
while(i--)
  exec = myAlert(exec);

exec();
```

If you try to do this:

```
var i = 5;
while(i--){
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert(5);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Then the browser runs ALL of the setTimeouts at the same time, so 5 seconds later, they ALL execute.

Comment: Where is the function returned by `myAlert()` invoked? (Note also that the pseudo-recursion is only needed if the real-world case actually uses an alert, which sounds like a pretty annoying function; I'm vaguely hoping the real code does something else and the alert was just for testing.)

Comment: That's a good point, I forgot the exec() command at the very end of my code.

Comment: Note that the OP provided some quite different code in a comment under my answer, code that doesn't use `alert()` at all. I've edited it into the question (still waiting for the OP to confirm I interpreted the comment correctly) and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I saw that, but you've already answered it. I'm not even going to bother =P

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when `setTimeout` runs the for loop would have finished so that `i` would be equal to the last value it had. you can use any of the following ways to capture/save the value of `i` for each callback.

**You can use a closure like this**

```
  for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ ) {
    (function(box){
       setTimeout(function(){ 
          groopBox.eq(box).slideToggle(1000) 
       }, box*2000)
    })(i);

  }
```

**Or you can use a function like this**

```
  for ( var i=0 ; i<groopBox.length ; i++ ) {
    slideBox(i);
  }

  var slideBox = function ( box ) {
     setTimeout(function(){ 
        groopBox.eq(box).slideToggle(1000) 
     }, box*2000)
  };
```

Comment: Did you test this? In the first block you're passing `undefined` as the first argument to `setTimeout()` (calling the anonymous function immediately on each iteration).

Comment: why all functions run and at last the setTimeOut run?i want alert something after setTime out run.but when i put alert after setTimeOut line,it first run alert then run setTimeout what should i do?